# あるWebサービスから携帯キャリアにSMS、MMSを送信しようとしています。 送信制限、受信制限はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mail

あるWebサービスから携帯キャリアにSMS、MMSを送信しようとしています。
送信制限、受信制限はあるのでしょうか？
また制限がある場合は、その回避方法はどうしているのでしょうか？
例えば外部サービスのSendGridを利用したら回避できるとかですか？

Comment: 本Webサービスに登録しているユーザ全員(例：5万人)にSMSまたはMMSを一斉送信しようとしています。

Comment: 情報を追記するならコメントではなく本文を直接編集した方が良いでしょう。検索すれば色々情報があるようです。それらを調べるか、直接携帯キャリアに問い合わせれば良いのでは？ [SMS送信APIのオススメサービス5つを紹介！比較ポイントを解説](https://liskul.com/sms-api-43448), [SMS送信でAPIを導入する前に気をつけておきたい3つの比較ポイント](https://www.smsnavi.com/qa/about_api/)

Comment: twillioも制限については明言していないですね。https://cloudapi.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/206364921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMSはおいておいて。一言に SMS といっても、通信事業者（キャリア）固有の仕様があるので、まずは、SMS 送信サービス事業者に相談したほうが良いのではないかと思います。
前にメディア SMS というサービスを利用したことがあります。CSV で送信者リストを用意し、それをサービス側にアップロードすることで一斉送信を実装しました（開発言語：C#）。ご参考までに。